# Сравнение двух файлов. node.js или git

Tags: node.js, xml, git

Есть файл xml , переодически он перезаписывается, но по сути на выходе изменения не большие.

Хотелось бы парсить после загрузки не весь файл по новой, а только то что удалилось (чтобы удалить неактуальное) и то что появилось (что бы добавить новые данные).

Я смотрел такие бибилиотеки как chokidar npm:
1) Они постоянное генерируют события , значит если я перепешу файл, то он просто скажет мне что удалилось все, и потом куча событий с информацией что добавилось всё. По сути проблемы не решат
2) Хотя может возможно перезаписать файл не по новой, а только отличающие части?

Так же может есть возможность решить этот вопрос с помощью git?

Comment: Что бы сравнить с предыдущей версией нужно как минимум её иметь. А если у вас есть две версии файла (два файла), то на них можно хоть diff натравить. Другое дело, что пытаться понять по diff-у что же поменялось в xml это вообще говоря нетривиально.

Answer (score 1):

Иногда проще это решить через git. Всё зависит от характера изменений. Если порядок строк в исходном и последующем файле не меняется, то проще использовать git, например, таким образом: после предполагаемого изменения делать `git commit -a -m "new commit"`, а затем проверять получившиеся изменения `git log -p`. При этом, если изменений не было, то нового коммита не создастся и это тоже удобный критерий мониторинга изменений.

Comment: спасибо. А вот допустим git diff выводит разницу в консоль, а есть способ выводить это в файл, который потом пропарсить можно? Просто было бы идеально

Comment: Всё можно выводить в файл, добавив конструкцию ` > file` в конец комманды